# How to use scrollTop in jQuery when scrolling within a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, scrolltop

[image]
The left is the what I'm trying to scroll...it scrolls just a little bit and then stops.  It seems to scroll the same amount each time too.

I am trying to get the scrollTop using jQuery to work on page load when the content I am trying to scroll to is located in within a div.  The current implementation doesn't do anything

## javascript

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function (){
            //$(this).animate(function(){
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $("#test4").offset().top
                     }, 2000);
            //});
    });
</script>
```

## html

```
<div class="row">
    <div class = "span12">
    
        <div class = "row">
        
            <div class = "span2">
            
                <div style="height:480px;font:12px Georgia, Garamond, Serif;overflow:auto;">
                
                    <div id = "test1">Test1</div>
                    <div id = "test2">Test2</div>
                    <div id = "test3">Test3</div>
                    <div id = "test4">Test4</div>
                
                </div>
            </div>
        
        
            <div class = "row">
                <div class = "span8">
                    Other content on the page
                </div>
            </div>
        
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works here: http://jsfiddle.net/FYHXC/ . Are you sure your page has vertical scrolling because it's too big for the window?

Comment: do you have enough content to scroll in you page.

Comment: This does work: http://jsfiddle.net/FYHXC/1/

Comment: @JaiPSah I do have enough content to be scrolled.

Comment: @PulkitMittal that seems to be the same as what I have, but it doesn't seem to work.  It scroll just a little bit (the same amount) each time and then stops.

Comment: @sharataka can you please make it clear what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: @JaiPSah I'd like the content in span2 (the thumbnail in the image above) to scroll to the selected image on page load.  What seems to be happening now is that the entire page scrolls down (left and right) instead of just the left (thumbnails).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have changed your code little bit you can [find the fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ezge8/1/).

this is the js code i have used:

```
$('.sss').animate({
    scrollTop: $(".test5").offset().top
}, 2000);​
```

here

```
$('.sss')
```

is the holder which holds the sidelinks