# jquery animate/scrollTop to multiple anchors inside divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, scrolltop

I'm having a problem implementing relatively complicated auto-scroll functionality on my page.  This displays the issue in my code...

http://codepen.io/d3wannabe/pen/XXxdQq

I have multiple divs on my page (blue,red,green in my example) that I not only want to be able to scroll to (which the top 3 buttons in my example achieve perfectly), but I want to be able to scroll WITHIN (which the bottom 3 buttons represent my best attempt at).

The thing I can't figure out, is why the scroll within function works well on my first div ("scrollTo3rdBlueItem" button), but then less accurately with the other divs ("scrollTo3rdRedItem" and "scrollTo3rdGreenItem" buttons).  In my full web application (which obviously has more data to scroll through), I basically see that the lower down the page the parent div is positioned, the less accurately I'm able to scroll within it.

I'm struggling to identify much of a pattern though so can't simply try tweaking the offset values.  Any ideas what I might be doing wrong here would be hugely appreciated!!

...since I wasn't allowed to post this without quoting code - here's the jquery function you can see in my codepen!

```
function scrollToParent(parentID){
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $('#'+parentID).offset().top}, 500);
 }
function scrollToChild(parentID, childID){
      //first focus on the parent
  scrollToParent(parentID);

      $('#'+parentID).animate(
        {scrollTop: $('#'+ childID).offset().top - 100}
        , 500);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## UPDATE

Answer here was COMPLETETLY wrong. Left here to preserve the comments.

## UPDATE 2

Got IT! You need to take in to account the offset of the parent div. Update your **scrollToChild** function to the below;

```
  $('#'+parentID).animate(
    {
      scrollTop: $('#'+ childID).offset().top - $('#'+parentID).offset().top
    }, 500);
```

Comment: the element ids are unique aren't they?  I'm trying to scroll to heading3 in blueDiv, heading8 in redDiv, and heading13 in greenDiv?  Sorry if I'm misunderstanding your point!

Comment: Yeah that's not it... all the elements are unique in this example. I'm getting the same inconsistent results. Funny thing is, when I scroll down, and then back up, and THEN I press the button that goes to heading3 in the Blue Div, this one also overshoots its target!

Comment: To elaborate on that: it looks like heading3, heading8 and heading13 are being scrolled to the top of the viewport (i.e. the browser is trying to scroll them up to absolute position top:0, in stead of to the top of the visible div that they are in!

Comment: My mistake, scrub this answer. I'll leave it here for the comments, but yeah, I read the example completely wrong.

Comment: @LaurensSwart Could this be because offset() is being used? It seems to me as if offset() is relative to the top of the page. I'd suggest using offset().top - $(window).height().

Comment: I thought so too in the beginning, especially since here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13171191/how-to-use-scrolltop-in-jquery-when-scrolling-within-a-div it is suggested to use `position().top` in stead of `offset().top`, but in my Chrome this gave exactly the same (wrong) result.. I'm still trying though! I've had this problem in the past and in the end I gave up, so now is a good time to pick up this nasty old glitch! :D

Comment: Awesome, that works perfectly - thank you both for all the effort - never would have got that on my own!

Comment: No worries. *Happy Coding!*

Comment: Nice! I noticed it had to be something like that because the green div was always scrolling completely to the bottom, while the red one usually stopped somewhere half way. Nice fix! Still wondering what the difference is between `offset()` and `position()` though, because I really thought using `position()` in this case would also have worked (the jQuery documention says it should...)

Comment: It's a strange one indeed. If I had to guess, I'd say that position doesn't account for any css layout updates such as margin/padding/positioning whereas offset does. This is unconfirmed, just a theory.

Comment: Could be... Well, for `position()`, subtracting the position of the container div also works :) http://www.webl.es/stackoverflow/jquery_scroll.html